# Is it possible to write into a RichTextBox at a given line, column?

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox

I have a WinForm with a RichTextBox.
I am trying to write into the RichTextBox at a given line and column:
Here is the code:
public Form1()
{

```
        InitializeComponent();

        richTextBox1 = new RichTextBoxWithMouseSelectionFixed();
        richTextBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(62, 46);
        richTextBox1.Name = "richTextBox1";
        richTextBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(461, 391);
        richTextBox1.TabIndex = 0;
        richTextBox1.Text = "";
        richTextBox1.HideSelection = false;
        Controls.Add(richTextBox1);

        int line = 3; 
        int column = 5;
        GoToLineAndColumn(richTextBox1, line, column);
    }

    private RichTextBoxWithMouseSelectionFixed richTextBox1;


    private void GoToLineAndColumn(RichTextBox richTextBox1, int line, int column)
    {
        int offset = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < line - 1 && i < richTextBox1.Lines.Length; i++)
        {
            offset += richTextBox1.Lines[i].Length + 1;
        }
        richTextBox1.Focus();
        richTextBox1.Select(offset + column, 0);
    }
```

I tryed to write with:
richTextBox1.AppendText("currentWord");

and also with:
richTextBox1.Text = "currentWord";

but in both cases the currentWord is written in the first line at column 0.

Answer (score 0):

The RichTextBox class has properties you can use to write text to a specific index in it. first you define the zero based index of the line and column you would like to write to and then you get the index of the first character in that line like below

```
// define the index of the line and the column of the line you want to write to in the rich text box
int lineIndex = 2;
 // zero-based index of the line
int columnIndex = 10;
// Get the index of the first character in that line you specified above
int index = richTextBox.GetFirstCharIndexFromLine(lineIndex) + columnIndex;
//declare the string you wish to paste
string mytext = "Write to this section only";
//Use the SelectionStart and SelectionLength properties to write the text
richTextBox.SelectionStart = index;
richTextBox.SelectionLength = mytext.Length; 
// clear any previous selection
richTextBox.SelectedText = mytext;
```

Comment: Thank you for the input. There is no text in the TextBox. I published the code. What I want is to position the first text at the coordinate (line, column) within the TextBox.

Comment: Set the Selection Length of the RichTextBox to the length of the text you wish to paste, let me update the code

Comment: To insert text, you don't want to specify `SelectionLength`. In any case, not related to the new text, unless you want to highlight it after you have inserted it

Comment: @Jimi, Very true, let me update the code and would would like OP to accept my answer if it worked for him.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I found is by adding empty lines before the text and blank characters before the text:

```
    private void WriteAtLineAndColumn(RichTextBox richTextBox1, string text, int line, int column)
    {
        // Insert blank lines at the beginning of the RichTextBox.
        for (int i = 0; i < line - 1; i++)
        {
            richTextBox1.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);
        }
        int index = richTextBox1.GetFirstCharIndexFromLine(line - 1);
        richTextBox1.Select(index, 0);
        string spaces = new string(' ', column);
        richTextBox1.SelectedText = spaces + "This is a sample text";

        // Insert the text at the desired position.
        richTextBox1.Select(richTextBox1.GetFirstCharIndexFromLine(line - 1) + column, 0);
        richTextBox1.SelectedText = text;
    }
```